# logrotate cron job not rotating certain logs

Tags: logging, cron, logrotate, cron.daily, log-rotation

I added two scripts in "logrotate.d" directory for my application logs to be rotated.
This is the config for one of them:

```
<myLogFilePath> {
  compress
  copytruncate
  delaycompress
  dateext
  missingok
  notifempty
  daily
  rotate 30
}
```

There is a "logrotate" script in "cron.daily" directory (which seems to be running daily as per cron logs):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "logrotate_test" >>/tmp/logrotate_test
#/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf >/dev/null 2>&1
/usr/sbin/logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.conf &>>/root/logrotate_error

EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

The first echo statement is working.
**But I find my application logs alone are not getting rotated, whereas other logs like httpd are getting rotated ** 

**And I also don't see any output in the mentioned "logrotate_error" file** (has write permission for all users).

However the syslog says: **"logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]"**

But when I run the same "logrotate" in "cron.daily" script manually, everything seems working fine.

Why is it not rotating during daily cron schedule? Am I doing something wrong here? 
It would be great if I get this much needed help.

**UPDATED:**
It looks like, it's because of selinux - the log files in my user home directory has restrictions imposed by selinux and the when logrotate script is run:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/logrotate from getattr access on the file /home/user/logs/application.log
```

Comment: From memory there is a `-d` option to logrotate.  You should try that one too.  If it's confusing, add the output to your question.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried -d (debug option) when running manually, and everything looked fine, it says that my application logs needs to be rotated.

Answer (score 9):

SELinux was restricting the access to logrotate on log files in directories which does not have the required SELinux file context type. "/var/log" directory has **"var_log_t"** file context, and logrotate was able to do the needful. So the solution was to set this on my application log files and it's parent directory:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t <directory/logfile>
restorecon -v <directory/logfile>
```

Comment: See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/39006 for a complete explanation of the problem and the solution.

Comment: Thanks you! This saved my day. I was already losing my mind ;-)